# Google Wallet Online API

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, android-pay

After a long research of almost two days I found myself helpless and now putting a question here.

I need to implement Google Wallet into my website. My web app is offering few online services and to use them a user has to pay. I have successfully integrated PayPal into my web app. Google wallet is my second target , what I figure out is to use Instant Buy API but I only need a java code for both server and client side which is not available, then I came across [Google Wallet Online API (java)](http://wallet-online-java.googlecode.com/git/doc/index.html?help-doc.html)but unable to understand how to use the API.

Again searched a lot for samples of the same but unable to find, any help or reference to any implementation of the above API is appreciated.

Comment: is [this](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/objects/quickstart-java) what you're looking for?

Comment: We've been searching for a Google Wallet web API as well and can't find it. We'd like to send money to users, and know this would work via their Android API, but need to do this from our website, not an Android app. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/discovery-and-monetization/payment-request/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to start researching the Google Wallet API with the [Wallet developers](http://developers.google.com/wallet) page which has live buy flow demos.

This [page](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/which-api) also has a good summary of available Wallet APIs.

Depending on what you are selling on your website, you are probably interested in the:

1. [Wallet for digital goods API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/)
2. [Wallet Instant Buy for web API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/)

Both of the above APIs have quick start samples in multiple languages (including Java).

Answer (score 0):

We have quick start samples for both payment APIs in Java:

1. Wallet Instant Buy Sample in Java: 
   https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/web/quickstart-java
2. Wallet Digital Goods API Sample in Java:(only for virtual and digital goods)
   https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/samples#iap-java